# How can the formal charge of the B in the Lewis structure of BF4(-) ion be minus one?

Tags: lewis-structure, formal-charge

> How can the formal charge of the $\ce{B}$ in the lewis structure of
>   $\ce{BF4-}$ ion be minus one ?

I draw the lewis structure of $\ce{BF4-}$ ion such like the following:
I put $\ce{B}$ in the central position and make single bonds between $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{F}$s, then completed the octet of $\ce{F}$s.

But in such a structure, the formal charge of $\ce{B}$ is $-1$, and the FC of $\ce{F}$s is 0.However, we know that if someone is going to get a minus FC, it should be the one whose electronegativity is the highest, and in this example this rule is not followed, so what is the reason for that ?

Comment: Formal charges are assigned assuming pure covalent bonds, so it often goes *against* electronegativity.

Comment: Couple of comments. 1) [Please don't use MathJax in titles as far as possible.](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/261/16683) 2) Please use $`\ce{...}`$ for chemical formulae and expressions. See [here](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) for more info.

Comment: @DHMO I didn't quite understand what you have said, could you explain what you mean with more details  ?

Comment: Formal charge is the charge an atom would have if all the bonds were cleaved homolytically, ignoring electronegativity.

Comment: There's a reason it's a called a "formal" charge and not just charge.

Comment: @Zhe So what is that reason ?

Comment: Because it's a formality and not real.

Comment: @Zhe so how does this knowledge, which I have already known,  help me with solving the problem ?

Comment: I would say you don't understand because if you're trying to use formal charge together with electronegativities, you're doing it wrong. The formal charge is a formality for keeping track of total charges in the species. It doesn't reflect the charge distribution on any atom because it assumes a equal sharing of electrons in any bond. And if you understand this is the case, why are you trying to use it in a way that it shouldn't be used?